# Possible data corruption when copying geodatabases to and from multiple hard drives

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-management

I hope to manage an ArcGIS Pro project and geodatabase between my personal laptop, external hard drive, and a shared office computer.

For the current project, I am accessing files from one geodatabase as well as shapefiles in a separate folder. The below graphic displays my file structure on my external hard drive.

[image]

If I copy and paste the entire folder (including the shapefile folder and geodatabase) from the external hard drive to the desktop of either computer, will the geodatabase be corrupted?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  Questions asking for "best practices" are by their nature too broad because they seek multiple answers and likely to result in opinion-based answers.  Consequently, they are a poor fit for focussed Q&A.

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this using a test ArcGIS Pro project?  I would expect there to be no issue but I would need to test to be sure.

Comment: If all share a network, I'd recommend version management software (Subversion, GIT,...) which would organize your access and  prevent loss.

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer the question that is asked "will the geodatabase become corrupt if I copy it from an external harddrive to the computer":  **no.**

There is probably much more to your question than that, but thats what you've asked. Copying files does not corrupt them. If they are becoming corrupt, something is going on. But file copy is a fundamental operating system ability.